# How do you find the bottom scrollable position in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

In an android scrollView, how do you find the lowest position in the scrollview so you can then use the `scrollTo(x,y)` method to scroll right to the bottom. **I need the actual numeric value**. Using the `getHeight()` method does not ever return the right value. The scrollbar will sometimes scroll to the end, and sometimes not reach it. There is a linearlayout with a textview in the scrollview. There has to be something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I found a quick hack if anyone is interested.

```
sView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
sView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
y = sView.getScrollY();
sView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

This will jump down to the bottom of the scrollable, collect y, then jump up again. It happens so fast it is not visible and it will get you the bottom value of y every time. You have to call focus down twice or else y will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just scroll to the end, you should be able to just use fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN). If you need a particularly numerical value based on the height of the scroll view, you will have to subclass your scroll view and override onSizeChanged, which will give you the actual numerical height. Keep in mind onSizeChanged will only be called after onResume, and will not necessarily be called every time your activity resumes.

Part of the reason why you sometimes scroll to the end and sometimes don't is probably because of a race condition. Sometimes your scroll happens before other important things (like populating the view) have happened, so it doesn't appear to do anything.

Try posting your calls to your scroll view's handler:

```
yourScrollView.post(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
  }
};
```

Sometimes even adding a short delay can help:

```
yourScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
  }
}, 200);
```